# Meaning of 真であるとして

Tags: meaning

> 話し手が真であるとして提示している事象の表示

In the above sentence, I'm guessing '真であるとして' means 'as if it is the truth/real', but I'm guessing I might be misunderstanding 'であるとして' so I thought I'd ask for clarification. Also stumbling a bit with understanding '事象の表示' ('representation of events'?), but I think that's because I'm not understanding the sentence fully.

Comment: It's actually a noun phrase rather than a sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

～であるとして can mean two things: **"as being..."** or **"supposing that.../if..."** It looks as if you had given both meanings to a single instance of the phrase. It can only be one or the other at one time, and here, "as being..." is the correct sense.

The 事象の表示 would be "manifestation of the phenomenon (or phenomena)" or some such. But there are many candidates for the translation of the 表示 (one of them being "representation") and without context, it is hard to judge which one is the best suited.

Translated, the whole phrase should be parsed as follows:

> （manifestation （of the phenomenon （which the speaker is presenting as being a truth）））

(Am I segmenting the phrase properly? If not, could someone please correct me? I'm new to this...)